# Why IS NULL not working in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a category table where there are some entries. I want to show those category names which don't have any `mpid` , `spid` and `pid`. I don't know what I did wrong, but my `IS NULL` statement is not working in here. My sql:

```
function select_all_main_category_info() {
        require 'db_connect_temp.php'; 
        $sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_category WHERE mpid IS NULL AND spid IS NULL AND pid IS NULL AND deletion_status=1";
        if (mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql)) {
            $query_result=mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql);
            return $query_result;
        } else {
            die("Query Problem". mysqli_error($db_connect));
        }
    }
```

My PHP code to display category names:

```
<?php 

include_once 'applications.php';

$res=select_all_main_category_info();

while($info=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    echo $info['category_name'];
    echo '<br>';
}
```

The category table:
[image]
Can anyone please help?

Comment: *"but my IS NULL statement is not working in here"* - Which one(s)? You have many.

Comment: and the schema and what this method does `select_all_main_category_info()` and how it's called; question's too unclear here.

Comment: It's the function name inside where my code is written. Let me edit the code section.

Comment: Edited now.@Fred-ii-

Comment: `IS NULL` and "not empty" are different animals. Any errors also? you might have a variable scoping issue, unless you're getting some results.

Comment: I can't see any error but no result has come either

Answer (score 0):

My issue is resolved. I wasn't aware of the `IS NULL` and empty statement. Here's the SQL which fixed the issue:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_category WHERE mpid ='' AND spid ='' AND pid='' AND deletion_status=1";
```

Comment: [Looks like I was right....](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47641259/why-is-null-not-working-in-sql?noredirect=1#comment82241142_47641259).